# How to copy from vim to google chrome?

Tags: vim, text-editor

I want to select all contents of a file and copy it to google chrome. I have tried shift-ctrl-c but it isn't working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the beginning of the file, type in the key sequence to copy the entire contents to the clipboard:

<kbd>:</kbd><kbd>%</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>

if you want to copy just one line, move the cursor to the start of the line you want, and type in the following key sequence:

<kbd>:</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>

or like stated in another answer here, copy the entire contents to the clipboard `+` instead of the `*` registers try:

<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>

for these key sequences to work, you need to have `gvim` installed, or one similar to it, that will make it so `vim` has the ability to copy to the clipboard. Below are 3 packages that will enable the **+clipboard** for `vim`.

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install vim-athena
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gtk
```

I personally prefer `vim-gnome` but any of them should work fine.

Comment: I tried :%y+.. But it is giving an error E850: Invalid register name

Comment: @In78 If you install `vim-gnome`, or one of the `vim` packages like stated in my answer, then it works fine from `vim`, `vi`, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Using a pastebin service

```
pastebinit -i <my_file> -b http://paste.ubuntu.com
```

You will see an URL. Open the URL in Chrome.

Comment: Learn something new today.  Thank you!  +1

Answer (score 5):

Use the keystrokes below:

<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>

to copy the text to the * or + registers:
Explanation:

- `gg`

  - gets the cursor to the first character of the file
- `"*y`

  - Starts a yank command to the register `*` from the first line, until...
- `G`

  - go the end of the file

Reference:

Shamelessly copied from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620018/copy-all-the-lines-to-clipboard/1620029#1620029

Comment: All is open source ;) +1